# Pages with Flash won't load until user clicks the X (stop) button on IE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, internet-explorer

I am building a flash application using flex. From time to time, I see an issue in IE 7 and 8 where the user logs into the site and the browser content pane is completely grey and the entire page (html, javascript and flash) won't load until the user clicks the X (Stop) button next the address bar. As soon as the X is clicked, the html loads and then the swf file loads immediately.

This doesn't happen for me or any other developers on the project so it is very hard to diagnose. The users are all using the latest flash player. The only difference between our setups that I can think of is that we have the debug version of flash player and they probably do not.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce it? 
Do you have a pc where it happens? If so, maybe you could look in a tool like Charles if everything gets loaded properly...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there could be a long running script-originated request executing, which is called before onDomLoad is fired.  Try moving all your JS includes to the bottom of the page, and deferring any dom-manipulation or requests until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: sounds simple enough. I'll give it a try. Thanks.